# very slow dns resolution

Tags: dns, systemd-resolved

I haven't found a thread on this specific issue :

My DNS resolution can be very long on linux. Generaly after a while using it (after 3/4h uptime).

- I am using a specific DNS for specific domains : `kube.toto` and `toto`. This DNS can be slow.
- For all other websites, I should be using the default dns (from my local network) : this dns resolver is fast.

Here is a copy of my `/etc/resolv.conf` (automatically generated, it is a symlink) :
 a different way,

```
 [... comments]
 nameserver 127.0.0.53
 search kube.toto toto
```

It seems like the dns resolver proxy 127.0.0.53 tries to reach the vpn dns resolver even for names it should not...

If anyone has a solution.